# Cucumber pickle's path_to_pickle usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle

I'm just having a look at pickle (on Rails 3) for simplifying my steps and paths in cucumber. I'm having trouble using the path_to_pickle for creating edit paths.

I installed pickle with:

```
  rails g pickle --paths --email
```

I have a Scenario for editing a ledger:

```
  Scenario: Edit a ledger
    Given I have a ledger with name "Digitech"
    When I go to the ledger's edit page
    And I fill in "Name" with "Test Ledger"
    And I press "Update Ledger"
    Then I should be on the ledgers page
    And I should see "Ledger was successfully updated."
```

I'm using the standard paths which pickle generates:

```
when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? page$/                           # eg. the forum's page
  path_to_pickle $1

when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? #{capture_model}(?:'s)? page$/   # eg. the forum's post's page
  path_to_pickle $1, $2

when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? #{capture_model}'s (.+?) page$/  # eg. the forum's post's comments page
  path_to_pickle $1, $2, :extra => $3                           #  or the forum's post's edit page

when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? (.+?) page$/                     # eg. the forum's posts page
  path_to_pickle $1, :extra => $2                               #  or the forum's edit page
```

I get this error when trying to run cucumber

```
When I go to the ledger's edit page                 # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:19
  Could not figure out a path for ["the ledger"] {:extra=>"edit"} (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/paths.rb:32:in `path_to'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:20:in `/^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/'
  features/ledger/manage_ledgers.feature:61:in `When I go to the ledger's edit page'
```

I read on the mailing list that path_to_pickle needed attention but that was back in September, is this still the case?

Should I be using something like polymorphic_path(model($1))?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up giving up on path_to_pickle and using polymorphic path.  This is a step I have written for specifically capturing the edit page.  You can replace the 'edit' for a more general solution

```
when /^the edit page for #{capture_model}$/ 
  polymorphic_path(model!($1), :action => "edit")
```

Comment: Tried that with the When line: 'When I go to the edit page for ledger "Main"' and I get an error 'The model: 'ledger "Main"' is not known in this scenario.'. How does polymorphic_path know which ledger to edit? Or how do I form my when statement to suit that path command?

Comment: When you are using pickle's model! method, you need to make sure to use a pickle step to identify the instance of the model you want first.  It takes the string "that ledger" as input so the value it is referencing must be set before the reference is used.  Instead of using "I have a ledger ...", you need to use "a ledger exists ...".  If you want to keep your current syntax, add a "a ledger should exist ..." line to setup the pickle data.